# When using setTimeout do you have to clearTimeout?

Tags: javascript

Someone told me that when you use `setTimeout` you must clear it with `clearTimeout`. I can understand before the timeout runs out, but why after? Or is it untrue?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

It's not true - there's no harm in clearing a timeout after it has finished, but it's not necessary.

Per the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-cleartimeout):

> If handle does not identify an entry in the list of active timers of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope object on which [clearTimeout] was invoked, the method does nothing.

In other words, it's a no-op; nothing happens, and no error will be thrown.

Answer (score 97):

You don't actually need to use `clearTimeout`, you only use it if you wish to cancel the timeout you already set before it happens.

It's usually more practical to use `clearInterval` with `setInterval` because `setInterval` usually runs indefinitely.

Answer (score 36):

`clearTimeout` is only necessary for cancelling a timeout.  After the timeout fires, it can safely be left alone.  `clearInterval` is much more typically necessary to prevent it from continuing indefinitely.

Comment: Would it no cause memory leak if the `setTimeout` is called repeatedly in a loop without clearing it using `clearTimeout`?

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer This is why setInterval() exists

Answer (score 22):

No, `setTimeout` stops running after 1 call. In order to stop `setInterval` however, you must use `clearInterval`. If you create an endless loop of `setTimeout` then `clearTimeout` could be used.

Answer (score 18):

No reason to clear it after it's completed. Your friend might have been confused with `setInterval`.

Comment: could you take a look here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815917/the-timeout-does-not-clear-all-instances-in-react-js

Answer (score 0):

It is always best practice to `cleartimeout` after using setTimeout.
let's take a scenario you are using `setTimeout` on `/abc`
page. and you set a time of 10s. and now you move to `/something` page before the timeout is completed(less than 10s). but `setTimeout` is still running so now you are on `/something` page and timeout ends the time and the callback function will run on `/something` page in the callback function, you might be using a window object which may affect your `/something` page and result in an error or unexpected result.

conclusion- always use `cleartimeout` to remove unexpected errors.

Please add your thoughts if I am wrong

Comment: That's nonsense. If you move to a different page then the entire program running in the previous page will be terminated.

Comment: @Quentin you should have a look at memory leaks in javascript, it might also be the case when elements are removed from the DOM, also depend on whether you are using dynamic rendering or something like a SPA