# How to ClearTimeout of a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that will continuously reset every time a button is clicked, however, I am trying to clear that timer when a certain picture is on the screen. There are more things going on in the program but this is the general problem I am having. Here is what I have so far:

JavaScript:

```
function reset() {
  var f = document.getElementById("ff").onclick;
  var ft = setTimeout(function(){ dontf() }, 3000);
  f = ft;
}

function dontf() {
  document.getElementById("r").src="H.jpg";
}

function s() {
  if (document.getElementById("r").src == "file:///C:/Users/S.jpg") {
    clearTimeout(ft);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="reset(); s();" id="ff">Fd</button>
```

Comment: you declare ft iside a function so it is not going to be available outside of it.

Comment: After putting them outside of the function, I am getting syntax errors saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onclick' of null" directed towards the f variable.

Comment: What you have put outside ?

Comment: I added the two variables, f and ft to the outside of the function. I left f=ft inside of the function

Comment: and the whole var f.... var ft....  f = ft  no sense. do you think that timer is someone being bound to the click event? If yes, that is not the case.

Comment: Sorry if it doesn't make sense, I am very new to programming, I tried doing it without the variables before, but could not seem to get it to work, adding the variables was the only thing I could think of to make it work. And I did think it was bound as it was working before I tried clearing the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can look at this mate**

All you needed to do is define var ft in a scope which is accessible by both of the `dontf` and `s` funtion

```js
let timer;        
function reset() {
  const element = document.getElementById("resetButton");
  timer = setTimeout(function(){ addImageFunc() }, 3000);
}

function addImageFunc() {
console.log(timer); document.getElementById("addImage").src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";
}

function stopReset() {
  if (document.getElementById("addImage").src == "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350") {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="reset(); stopReset();" id="resetButton">Fd</button>
  <img id='addImage'>
</body>
</html>
```

> Suggestions

- Use proper naming convention for the variables and functions which will make your code more readable and easy debugging.
- Don't use var. use let or const.
- Try avoid using global scope variables unless there is no alternate way.

Comment: if button is clicked twice, you will still have a timer running.

Comment: @epascarello i don't see that happening. can you point it out please ?, I have added a console log you can try testing.

Comment: click button, sets ft (1). click button sets ft (2). Original ft (1) is still running, if you cancel it, you are cancelling (2) and (1) is still active.

Comment: @epascarello ***have a function that will continuously reset every time a button is clicked, however, I am trying to clear that timer when a certain picture is on the screen***  so untill the image loads any how user do not want to clearInterval and after that time(image is loaded) any setTimeout will be cleared.

Comment: @epascarello well no once image is loaded.than every time if condition clears interval.

Comment: But if the image is not loaded than it generates multiple intervals. :) Why is the if check just not before the timeout code? `if (not image) createTimer` :)

Comment: @epascarello than i need to write what op didn't wanted  :p anyway leave it op :) if you want you can read this up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391567/when-using-settimeout-do-you-have-to-cleartimeout

Answer (score 0):

The scope of ft is unreachable since it is defined inside of a function. Need to move it to a scope where the other method is able to reference it.

```
var ft;  // define it outside
function reset() {
  // var f = document.getElementById("ff").onclick; <<-- no clue what this is doing
  if (ft) window.clearTimeout(ft); // if it is running, remove it
  ft = setTimeout(dontf, 3000);
  // f = ft; <-- does not make sense
}

function dontf() {
  document.getElementById("r").src="H.jpg";
}

function s() {
  if (document.getElementById("r").src == "file:///C:/Users/S.jpg") {
    if (ft) clearTimeout(ft);
  }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of var f was to see when the button was clicked, which would then start the timeout of ft.  So every time the button was clicked, it would start a timer of dontf. I'm not sure how else I would do it

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You have already attached `onlick` event in HTML, here `<button onclick="reset(); s();" id="ff">Fd</button>`. You don't need to attach it again in javascript. What's more, correct way to do it in js is `document.getElementById("ff").onclick = reset` or (better) `document.getElementById("ff").addEventListener('click', reset)`. Your code do nothing, it is unnecessary. This: `f = ft;` also

Comment: @kotlet not sure what that comment has to do with my code... AS you can see I commented out those lines.... Your answer is basically mine, only answered 6 minutes after me.

Comment: @epascarello . It was answer to demdragons comment of your answer :)