# Hiding components: adding a class or removing from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I want to add a class to a component after a set amount of time in React, however I am not sure the best way to do this. I want to add the "hidden" class to a loading image after a few seconds so it changes to display: none. Yet I am getting several different errors when I try this.

Here is the code for my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import earth from './earth.svg';

const loader = document.getElementsByClassName('loader');

 setTimeout(function(){
            loader.classList.add('hidden');
    }, 3000);


function Loader() {
  return (
    <div className="loader">
      <img src= {earth} alt="earth-loader" />
    </div>

  )
}

export default Loader;
```

The image loads, but after the set time I get errors. I get "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" or with document.querySelector earlier but I get "Cannot read property 'classList' of null" instead. I don't know why I get null or undefined errors since the loader class does display.

Could I also just remove the component from App.js after a few seconds?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
    <Navbar />
    <Loader />
    <Card />
    </div>
  );
}
```

What would be the best way to go about this in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically mixing React stuff with vanilla Javascript and DOM accesses (`document.getElementsByClassName`) and this most likely results in many different and complex errors. It is therefore advisable to stay within React completely and set classes within the React component lifecycles. That means **if you use React you should very rarely make use of the `document` global variable**.

**A better example with hidden classes**:

```
import React from 'react';
import earth from './earth.svg';

function Loader() {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  const classes = "loader" + (hidden ? " hidden" : "");

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      setHidden(true);
    }, 3000);
    return () => { clearTimeout(timeoutID); };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes}>
      <img src= {earth} alt="earth-loader" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Loader;
```

**A better example with conditional rendering**:

```
import React from 'react';
import earth from './earth.svg';

function Loader() {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      setHidden(true);
    }, 3000);
    return () => { clearTimeout(timeoutID); };
  }, []);

  if (hidden) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="loader">
      <img src= {earth} alt="earth-loader" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Loader;
```

Comment: theres no need for `clearTimeout` though  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391567/when-using-settimeout-do-you-have-to-cleartimeout

Comment: @gmoniava Unfortunately, this does not apply in React. If you don't clear the timeout and the component is unmounted before the timeout ends, you get an ugly error stating that you can not update state (by function `setHidden`) on an unmounted component.

Comment: Ah yeah in that case, yes

Comment: You are missing an empty array as second argument in useEffect