# The timeout does not clear all instances in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next code where i created a hook to handle the timeout function. The idea is, when the user will click on a button, the message should appear and to be cleared after an amount of time.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";
const useTimer = () => {
  const timer = useRef();
  const fn = useCallback((callback, timeout = 0) => {
    clearTimeout(timer.current);
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
      callback();
    }, timeout);
  }, []);

  const clearTimeoutHandler = () => {
    console.log("clear");
    return clearTimeout(timer.current);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return clearTimeoutHandler();
  }, []);

  return { fn, clearTimeoutHandler };
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const [list, updateList] = useState([]);
  const timer = useTimer();

  const removeItem = (id) => {
    updateList((list) => list.filter((x) => x.id !== id));
    timer.clearTimeoutHandler();
  };

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    const id = new Date();

    const element = {
      id: id,
      text: "text" + new Date()
    };

    updateList(list.concat([{ ...list, ...element }]));

    timer.fn(() => {
      removeItem(id);
    }, 2000);
  };

  const bottomMess = () => {
    setState({ m: "hi" });
    timer.fn(
      () => {
        setState(undefined);
      },
      2000
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={bottomMess}>Open bottom message</button>
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Open top message</button>
      {list.map((d) => (
        <h1>{d.text}</h1>
      ))}
      {state && (
        <div style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0 }}>
          bottom message {state.m}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

ISSUE: when I click on `Open top message` button 3 times, only the last message disappears, but I expect all to be removed.
 Where is the issue in the hook and how to make the hook workable?
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-fire-2xw0d5?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Your current implementation only keeps track of the last timer. You can return `timerId` from `fn` and accept `timerId` as an argument to `clearTimeoutHandler` function:

Try like this:

```
const useTimer = () => {
  const timer = useRef([]);
  const fn = useCallback((callback, timeout = 0) => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      callback();
    }, timeout);
    timer.current.push(timerId);
    return timerId;
  }, []);

  const clearTimeoutHandler = (timerId) => {
    return clearTimeout(timerId);
  };

  const clearAll = () => {
    timer.current.forEach((timerId) => clearTimeout(timerId));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return clearAll;
  }, []);

  return { fn, clearTimeoutHandler, clearAll };
};
```

[image: Edit aged-voice-tjwtso]

Comment: @Asking, check this out !!

Comment: it has now an issue. Before if i continously clicked on `Open bottom message` multiple times, the bottom message did not disappear , but now it disappear if i click multiple times. The previous behaviour was correct. Could you help?

Comment: I will have a look

Comment: @Asking, updated the codesandbox, you need to have another timer for bottom item and it should clear all the previous timers when a click happen. For that another  function called `clearAll` was exposed from `useTimer`.

Comment: it look good by i want to abstract all logic inside the hook. I tried to remove `clearTimeout(timer.current);` from my code (hook) and it almost worked, but it does not removed the last item from the top. Could you take a look, maybe there is a shorter way. Thanks a lot

Comment: if to use your example, how to remove a top message by clicking on it using: ` {list.map((d) => (
        <h1 onClick={() => removeItem()}>{d.text}</h1>
      ))}` , here i need the ID and timer iD, but how to get them there?

Comment: @Asking, you can change save the timerId along with the list item then you can pass the id from the click handler. I have updated the codesandbox