# Timeout id is not cleared in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
let ad1 = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Delayed for 1 second.");
}, "1000")
console.log(ad1, 'start')
clearTimeout(ad1)
console.log(ad1, 'end')
```

Here `console.log(ad1, 'end')` i expect that my `ad1` should be cleared but the id still there. 
 Why the id is not cleared and how to see if the timeout id is clearead in my situation?

Comment: The timeout *is* cleared, but the timeout ID (the number) doesn't just reassign itself on its own when the timeout is cleared. It's just a number.

Comment: By the way, you should use `1000` not `"1000"`

Comment: As [per the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout), clearTimeout "cancels a timeout previously established by calling `setTimeout()`." It doesn't do anything more than that, so the real question is: why did you "expect that my `ad1` should be cleared"? Nothing in the clearTimeout docs says that will happen.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, one more question in this context. If i have a button that trigger each time a setTimeout and user click 5 times the button, then if i want to clear all timeouts i need to store all ID's in array and after that to clear them in a loop or how i should clear the all 5 timeouts?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, as in this question. Here if i add 5 messages components and after that i removed them from ui at once, should i clear the timeouts or this is not required? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815917/the-timeout-does-not-clear-all-instances-in-react-js

Comment: @CertainPerformance, could you help please with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815917/the-timeout-does-not-clear-all-instances-in-react-js

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73816138) looks to give you your expected output

Comment: @Noam, if i add 5 timeouts that are trigered by a button that was clicked 5 times and i i want to clear all of them, how should i do this?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, my question is, if i add 5 timeouts that was triggered clicking a button 5 times, how should i remove them? Should i store them before in array and to loop trough it removing each timeout or not?

Comment: Yes, every timeout/interval is associated with a unique timer id, which you will have to save somewhere (like in an array) and then cancel (by iterating over that array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It does get clear out.
- So what's going on here is that this setTimeout return one ID that is stored in `ad1`, which immediately clearout because of synchronised nature of javascript.
- and then it will run line by line which prints start and end.
- Here below in my code it won't print **start** because I moved that `console.log("start")` in `setTimeout`.
- where as `console.log("end")`, which will be printed because it's not in side of `setTimeout`.

```js
console.log("JavaScript is a synchronous, blocking, single-threaded language.");
let ad1 = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(ad1, 'start')
  console.log("Delayed for 1 second.");
}, 1000)
clearTimeout(ad1)
console.log(ad1, 'end', "not inside setTimeout");
```